# Forming a single query requested by multiple components

Tags: reactjs, rest, graphql, apollo

I am thinking to move to graphQL from a standard REST API architecture. Currently I have a data wrapper which preloads a dataset after initialization with user info, and other meta data.

Is there a way for apollo client to build a single query requested by multiple components and send it to graphQL server after the components are loaded instead of sending separate queries for each component and form a data layer that is necessary for application to operate ?

What are the possibilities eventually other options to do this and make it better with GraphQL then the current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries in Apollo client have an option `fetchPolicy` with default value `cache-first` which means Apollo will try to read from your local cache first before attempting a network fetch. If you have multiple components requesting data that has been fetched already then no network calls will happen. Just ensure to return the `id` field of the requested data in your query even if your component doesn't use it to ensure proper caching.

Comment: Thats amazing, but what if i get users directly, and then get company(id: 1) { users }, will graphql understand that it is the same thing since it uses same schema ?

Comment: Yes. Caching happens based on the GraphQL type defined in the schema. In this case I assume ‘User’.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following graphql schema:

```
type Query {
    question(questionId: Int!): Question
    tag(tagId: Int!): Tag
}

type Question {
    questionId: Int!
    content: String!
}

type Tag {
    tagId: Int!
    tagName: String!
}
```

If you want to retrieve 2 objects in one request you can write the following qraphql request:

```
{
  question(questionId: 1) {
    questionId
    content
  }
  tag(tagId:1){
    tagId
    tagName
  }
}
```

As output, you will receive the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "question": {
      "questionId": 1,
      "content": "how to code in js?"
    },
    "tag": {
      "tagId": 1,
      "tagName": "js"
    }
  }
}
```